# My PDF is not shown in Skim unless the application is already running

Tags: auctex, viewers

I have my Emacs/AucTeX/Skim development environment all set up and working perfectly ... almost. My only problem is that when I select to view my PDF, then

- if Skim is running, the PDF will be shown in Skim, and
- if Skim is not running, the PDF will be shown in my default PDF viewer.

I would prefer it if Skim would launch if it's not already running. How can I do that?

This is the relevant portion of my `.emacs` file:

```lisp
;; Enable synctex
(setq LaTeX-command "latex -synctex=1")

;; The following only works with AUCTeX loaded
(require 'tex-site)
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
        (add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
            '("^pdf$" "."
              "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline %n %o %b")))
)

;; Use PDF mode by default
(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)
;; Make emacs aware of multi-file projects
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
```

Comment: Can you get at the command used to open the PDF? From the command line `open -a Skim somefile.pdf` will launch Skim if required.  Can you configure emacs to do that?

Comment: @Thruston I've updated my question with some more info about how I've configured my emacs.

Comment: You should customize `TeX-view-program-selection` and `TeX-view-program-list`.  I've never touched `TeX-output-view-style` to select the PDF viewer.  Note also that with [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=1d0d1ac642e1acc6db859458dfcb7a151d657ac1) built-in support for Mac OS viewers was enabled.

Comment: @giordano Thanks. I'm on TeX Live 2013; is the commit you mentioned part of that release?

Comment: No, it will be included in future AUCTeX 11.88 release.

Comment: @giordano Do feel free to turn your comment into an answer; there's only one more day of bounty available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should customize `TeX-view-program-selection` and `TeX-view-program-list`. I've never touched `TeX-output-view-style` to select the PDF viewer. Note also that with [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=1d0d1ac642e1acc6db859458dfcb7a151d657ac1) built-in support for Mac OS viewers was enabled and this will be included in future AUCTeX 11.88 release.

For example, add this code to your initialization file to set the viewers and associate them to each file type:

```lisp
(setq
 ;; Set the list of viewers for Mac OS X.
 TeX-view-program-list
 '(("Preview.app" "open -a Preview.app %o")
   ("Skim" "open -a Skim.app %o")
   ("displayline" "displayline %n %o %b")
   ("open" "open %o"))
 ;; Select the viewers for each file type.
 TeX-view-program-selection
 '((output-dvi "open")
   (output-pdf "Skim")
   (output-html "open")))
```

This will be the default behavior of AUCTeX 11.88, with the exception of Skim set as the PDF viewer.

Comment: @JohnWickerson  Does this suffice?  Or should I add an example, as well?

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having a little bit of difficulty getting things set up quite right (AucTeX keeps asking me for a "Printer") so if you could give a concrete example of text to put in a `.emacs` file that would be super. (I've awarded you the bounty in any case.)

Comment: Ok, I'll add it later today.

Comment: @JohnWickerson  Answer updated, I'm sorry for the delay.

Comment: Many thanks. That all seems to work very nicely for me.