# Auctex go to corresponding block between pdf and tex file

Tags: emacs, auctex

Texshop's <kbd>CMD+Click</kbd> can take you to the location of the current texts on its pdf/tex file. I am wondering how to do this in emacs/auctex?

Comment: Take a look at [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#I_002fO-Correlation) of the AUCTeX manual.  If you use Skim, [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180637/31416) is some information about the correct setup.